# How to do a group by in pandas dataframe and create a new column that iterates from 0 to the length of the group?

Tags: python, pandas

What I am looking to achieve is to do a group by on a certain field then with that group to create a new column that iterates from 0 to the length of that group.

Thanks

Comment: can you show a [mcve] and an sample output? I think what you need here is groupby cumcount, but might also be carterisan product.

Comment: YES! That was what I was looking for. I found that module before and for some reason I kept looking at cumsum instead of that... Thank you so much!!